# Accessing Futures with loops in flutter

Tags: android, for-loop, asynchronous, flutter, dart

I have a list which looks something like this:

```
indices = [ image_02, image_32, image_33 ]
```

I am using [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) package to store data such that every element in the above list has some data stored like this:

```
image_02 : 
    {
        image: "http://path//to//image//",
        link: "http://links//to//webpage//"
    }
```

To access the data I use:

```
var image_data = await storage.read(key: 'image_02');
```

Using this method, I can get the data stored in 'image_02' in the secure_storage.
However, I have over a few hundred data like this. Which is why, I have a list of indices that maintains a list of keys to access the stored data.

Now, I used for loop to iterate through the list like this:

```
for (var index in list) {
      var data = await storage.read(key: index);
      print(data);
    }
```

But the for loop only returns the first data. All the other results are null:

```
I/flutter (15384): {image: https://xxxxxxxxxxx.com/api/upload/image_slider/f323694602724b675a898ba0454561ee.png, link: https://www.xxxxxxx.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxx}
I/flutter (15384): null
I/chatty  (15384): uid=11004(com.xxxxxx.xxxxxx) Thread-3 identical 5 lines
I/flutter (15384): null
```

For now, I am working on test server, which has around 6 - 7 images. Is there any way to loop through a list and get data from a function that returns a future?

Comment: I mean, have you checked the obvious? Do the other values in your list just result in null regardless?

Comment: Yes, I've checked them, and the other values in the list don't return null, when used manually. The problem here is definitely the for loop that doesn't run asynchronously.

Comment: What makes you think the loop doesn't run asynchronously?

Comment: Good question. I only thought the loop was running asynchronously because the command `await storage.read....` returns values when they are run on async functions. I have past experience, when similar commands would return null if not run on async functions. However, since only the first value returns, I suppose, the loop doesn't get give enough time to let the app read data from the storage.

Comment: Also, SInce, I have so much data, I should probably look into using sqflite or something else.

Comment: The `await` handles waiting for the asynchronous call to `storage.read` to complete and get the value. This would be true with or without the loop. If the result of the future is returning null for most of values in your list, I'd suspect that the real problem has nothing to do with the loop. For example, maybe those keys really don't exist in the storage at the time you are trying to get them, or maybe there's a bug (or feature) in the package that causes back-to-back calls to `storage.get` to return null. There isn't really anything else I can speculate based on the amount of info here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202855/discussion-between-sowingfiber-and-abion47).